# How to store big text into database to call it as web blog post (MySql)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, blogs

I'm building a blog website in Spring Framework with java and I want my posts to be shown from a database dynamicly (mysql).

Question:
Can I store the whole article into the database to reduce the mass file creation for every article and produce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it is possible. Spring has a pagination feature that allows you to retrieve "n" number of items per page. You can see an example here [REST API PAGINATION](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-pagination-in-spring)

2) You can store the whole article in the database using the type `TEXT` (or `VARCHAR(MAX)` if using mssql)

3)Upload the image to your server directory and call the url on your web pages. For example, if the name of your website is http://example.com you can create an `/image` folder and upload your image here. So if the name of your image is `test.png`, in your article stored in your db, it'll will contain the html text `<img src="http://example.com/image/test.png"/>` (this will probably be escaped in your db)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
   You can easily do pagination with [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) (or [Spring Data REST](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/))
   For the reload you will need to use javascript (I would suggest AJAX call for post and view change)
2. Yes. Databases has a BLOB type, which may help you.
3. You can save it in DB or on machine's disk. I would suggest storing it on disk.

Comment: 1. what's the difference between non-REST and REST?
3. But for every image I want, I must transfer the image with filezilla and call it to the post?

Comment: Please read the documentation for those two.
You can upload file using your blog.

Answer (score 0):

1) Can the above be true?

- Yes. Refer below URL to see how to do it with spring data.
  https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/

2) Can I store the whole article into the database to reduce the mass file creation for every article and produce it

- Yes (using text or blob). However, you can use some sort of caching to optimize your performance further. (Redis cache etc)

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

3) What is the best way to store the images of the articles to be more comfortable for me to store and manage them instead of ftp transferring to server and calling from there.

- Upload images to your server directory where your are storing you website statics (htmls/js etc). Keep reference of images in DB against each article. Amazon s3 could be a good choice to host your website statics including images. You can easily find code online for it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much sir. I appreciate your answer!